# Input box with another single option in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, input

I have a simple inputBox to enter the ID of an employee:

```
    id = InputBox("Enter ID NUMBER of the employee")
    If id = "" Or Not IsNumeric(id) Then
        MsgBox "No ID entered"
        Call prepareToExit
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Until now it was sufficient for me but now I need to be able to enter another parameter in the dialog box which will represent whether the user will use the default settings of the program or want to enter another menu to choose options (for example to change the default folder to user difined).

Can somebody explain how to add this single option in the input box. 
I understood that it cannot be done with `InputBox` method.

All I need is another button like "Advanced..." to know if the user wants to go to additional settings.

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to create a UserForm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three options come to mind:
1. Use a tailored userform
2. Add another msgbox to ask about the extra option (yes/no)
3. Include the option in the entered string. This is rather simple here, but for such things, regular expressions can be very useful. It kind of depends on your target audience if this may seem too 'cryptical' for some users.

An example:

```
Dim rx, rxM
Dim ID As String
Dim IDvalue As Long
Dim optionFlag As Boolean

Set rx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
rx.Pattern = "^(\d+)(\+)?$"

ID = InputBox("Enter ID NUMBER of the employee" & vbCrLf & _
"Add '+' for advanced options, e. g. 100345+")

If Not rx.test(ID) Then
'If ID = "" Or Not IsNumeric(ID) Then
    MsgBox "No ID entered"
    Call prepareToExit
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set rxM = rx.Execute(ID)
    IDvalue = CLng(rxM(0).submatches(0))
    optionFlag = (rxM(0).submatches(1) = "+")
    MsgBox IDvalue & vbCrLf & optionFlag
End If
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I decided to build a userform to add more functionality.